# Libreoffice 4.1 not integrated into launcher properly

Tags: 12.04, unity, libreoffice, platform-integration

Running 12.04 64bit Ubuntu, and after installing Libreoffice 4.1 from the official ppa, i get this integration problem upon opening already existing text documents, them being .doc, .docx or .odt. Anyone have a solution?

[image: Screen1]

[image: screen2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. 4.1 doesn't seem to play with this version of Unity. You need to downgrade to 4.0, then download the menubar folder into a LO folder. If I try exactly this with 4.1 it crashes every time I touch the menu bar. But 4.0 seems fine.

See this thread:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2113397&page=3

I downloaded it from: 
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package...sed/lo-menubar

On 12.04 wit LO 4.0.4.2 ([download from archive](http://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/)), it works for me if I just copy whole folder CONTENTS/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/extensions/menubar to...well /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/extensions/ .
no reset necessary.
was looking for a quick solution, didn't want to reinstall 4.xx from repos. which may be 'cleaner', but heij... it works o_O